# solr tomcat utf-8

Tags: tomcat, unicode, utf-8, solr

I have a solr setting with tomcat, and I import data with jdbc from a data base but when I use none-unicode characters after importing the data, when sending the query it dose not recognize the query in the result

Comment: What are "non-Unicode characters"? Can you please clarify your question using more than one sentence?

Comment: yes, I of course, for example if I put some arabic characters in the data base I get problem.

Comment: *What* problem specifically?! Have you checked the /browse/ interface whether the data displays correctly there?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For UTF-8 support on Tomcat with solr you may want to check
[Why_don.27t_International_Characters_Work.3F](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/FAQ#Why_don.27t_International_Characters_Work.3F)
[URI_Charset_Config](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrTomcat#URI_Charset_Config)