# Handling umlauts and accents with Solr

Tags: solr, indexing, ascii, diacritics

We use Solr 3.6 to index a document collection (DBLP). The meta-data of some documents is in German. For handling umlauts and accents we use the ASCIIFoldingFilterFactory (see schema.xml).

When searching for `title:Unterstutzung` several results are returned but when searching for `title:Unterstützung` there are no results even though there are documents that have *Unterstützung* in their title field.

Using the analyzer in the admin web interface shows that the query term and the document terms are indexed and processed as expected. But why do we get no results when there is an umlaut in the query?

Definition for title field in schema.xml:

```
<fieldType name="text" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
                    <analyzer type="index">
                            <charFilter class="solr.HTMLStripCharFilterFactory"/>
                            <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
                            <filter class="solr.ASCIIFoldingFilterFactory"/>
                            <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory" generateWordParts="1" generateNumberParts="1" catenateWords="1" catenateNumbers="1" catenateAll="1" splitOnCaseChange="1" preserveOriginal="1"/>
                            <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
                            <filter class="solr.EnglishPorterFilterFactory"/>
                            <filter class="solr.RemoveDuplicatesTokenFilterFactory"/>
                    </analyzer>
                    <analyzer type="query">
                            <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
                            <filter class="solr.ASCIIFoldingFilterFactory"/>
                            <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory" generateWordParts="1" generateNumberParts="1" catenateWords="0" catenateNumbers="0" catenateAll="0" splitOnCaseChange="1" preserveOriginal="1"/>
                            <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
                            <filter class="solr.EnglishPorterFilterFactory"/>
                            <filter class="solr.RemoveDuplicatesTokenFilterFactory"/>
                    </analyzer>
            </fieldType>
```

Full schema.xml: http://pastebin.com/rQDw30nA

Analyzer output for *Unterstützung* in both document and query: http://pastebin.com/6cxSnGwP (In the query the processed term *unterstutzung* is highlighted)

Comment: How are you searching? Maybe encoding by client changes behavior you expect?

Comment: I'm searching using the Solr admin web interface and the SolrJ Java API.

Comment: also check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9290905/solr-tomcat-utf-8/9293107#9293107

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. It's working now. The problem was indeed the missing URIEncoding="UTF-8" attribute in the server.xml

Answer (score 3):

It is a simple encoding issue with Tomcat. The following attribute has to be added to the server.xml:

```
<Server ...>
 <Service ...>
   <Connector ... URIEncoding="UTF-8"/>
     ...
   </Connector>
 </Service>
</Server>
```

http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrTomcat#URI_Charset_Config

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue with Solr 1.4 a year ago, i am not quite sure if it can work for you too, but using a mapping filter can help you for that, in addition to ascii folding, there is the related part from my schema

```
 <analyzer type="index">
    <charFilter class="solr.MappingCharFilterFactory" mapping="mapping-ISOLatin1Accent.txt"/>
    <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt"/>
    <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory" generateWordParts="0" generateNumberParts="0" catenateWords="1" catenateNumbers="1" catenateAll="0"/>
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.RemoveDuplicatesTokenFilterFactory"/>
</analyzer>
<analyzer type="query">
     <charFilter class="solr.MappingCharFilterFactory" mapping="mapping-ISOLatin1Accent.txt"/>
     <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
     <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="true" tokenizerFactory="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
     <filter class="solr.ASCIIFoldingFilterFactory"/>
         <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt"/>
         <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory" generateWordParts="0" generateNumberParts="0" catenateWords="1" catenateNumbers="1" catenateAll="0"/>
         <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.RemoveDuplicatesTokenFilterFactory"/>
 </analyzer>
```

Mapping file is simply a text file having mappins like `'unicode' => 'Mapped char'` you can find plenty of examples depending on the language on google...

I hope it helps

Comment: Thanks for your idea but it was just a simple enocing issue with Tomcat.